# Generating xcarchive with .p12 certificate and .mobileprovision

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

My client sent me a .p12 file containing certificate + private key and a .mobileprovision file. I need to sign our app with their profile so that they could publish the app with their brand developer environment.

Then I import the .p12 in Keychain Access and the .mobileprovision in xcode (it is added in ~Library\MobileDevice\Provisioning Profiles...).

What I do is:

```
xcodebuild -target XXX -configuration Release -scheme XXX -sdk iphoneos7.0 CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: XXX" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" clean archive
```

Then i send the .xcarchive generated to my client so that he can sign it. But he encountered an error while signing:

```
Nov 13 13:40:58 iPhone installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff7a000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app xxx.xxxxx.xxx
Nov 13 13:40:58 iPhone installd[54] <Error>: unrecognized status -67068 from codesigning library
Nov 13 13:40:58 iPhone installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff7a000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.XUXLRl/foo_extracted/Payload/XXX.app/XXX: 0xe8008001
Nov 13 13:40:58 iPhone installd[54] <Error>: 0x2ff7a000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.XUXLRl/foo_extracted/Payload/XXX.app
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: That error is given in the headers as: `errSecCSStaticCodeNotFound =            -67068, /* cannot find code object on disk */`, so it looks like the `.app` is not there (or the executable is missing from the bundle).

Comment: @trojanfoe my client told me he was able to sign another app with the certificate and provisioning he provided to me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong when importing the profile. I never matched their profile with my appID, is it normal? I think i missed something in the provisioning and distributing process...

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure.  Have you examined the `.xcarchive` bundle to check that everything is there?  Also how do you send your client the `.xcarchive`? (using `.tar.gz` would seem like the best way to me).

Comment: I sent the `.xcarchive` in `.zip` file format. Also I'm able to open the .xcarchive in my XCode environment, so I guess everything is there...

Comment: I think my client tried to distribute for Ad Hoc and then install the generated IPA on his iPad. But he can't distribute for Ad Hoc if the provisioning profile used to sign the app does not contain the right app ID, that's right?

Comment: In other words: How can I associate my client provisioning profile with my app?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that error, but assuming your binary hasn't plain gone missing, I would try building your copy of the app with a distribution profile.

While it's possible to repurpose a dev build as production, xcrun+PackageApplication/Xcode organizer in general won't have the smarts to translate the entitlements (e.g. push notification environment, keychain access groups) and bundleID for you.

p.s. For the *client* to re-sign *you* don't strictly need their signing identities or provisioning profile, although it does make it easier to get entitlements and the bundleID right.